# How to get settings.json content from vscode api extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building a vscode extension, where i needed the content of settings.json file.
I tried the below one to get a specific value like *colorTheme*,

```js
const workSpaceConfig = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("editor");
console.log(workSpaceConfig.get("fontSize")); // which returns 14
```

What if want the whole content which is in settings.json, like the below.

Settings.json (Example),

```json
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Quiet Light",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  ...
}
```

Comment: How are you going to use them?  What form do they need to be in?

Comment: what happens with `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();`

Comment: Most extensions consume each of the settings they are interested in one by one. If you simply want the whole JSON file content, read it from the workspace folder. In short, the whole content is useless as the hierarchical configuration system has settings in other files as well.

Comment: @rioV8
https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbcf4c50

Comment: @LexLi Hmm ok..

Answer (score 4):

This might get you started, although it is unclear how you plan to use the returned information.

```js
  let all = await vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();

  let allAsJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(all));  // the key line

  const editorSettings = allAsJSON.editor;

//  ==> 
//    {
//      tabSize: 2,
//      fontSize: 12,
//      insertSpaces: true,
//      detectIndentation: false,
//      trimAutoWhitespace: true,
//      largeFileOptimizations: true,
//      semanticHighlighting: {
//        enabled: "configuredByTheme",
//      },
//      <etc.>
//    }

  const editorFontSizeSetting = editorSettings.fontSize;  // 14

  // all["editor"].fontSize ==> 14  // this also works
```

The alternative is to find the `settings.json` file, `JSON.parse()` it.

As @LexLi intimated in his comment, user settings can be overridden by workplace settings for example.